# Killing processes via python

Tags: python, process, termination

my knowledge of python is rather limited so I might just be poking in the dark...

What I am attempting to do is open a file, write some stuff in it and close it.

The problem I have is, what if that file is opened?

To fit my needs, it needs to be closed, no matter what's happening to it, so I can open it via python application.

So if I cant open a file that's open, I can try to force close it and then open it via python?

Found this lib: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It kind of does what I want, maybe I'm just missing on the how.

It currently returns me a list of all processes and gives me ids that I can use to kill processes.(find_procs_by_name, kill_proc_tree)

While in reality, I would like to close test.csv that is open in excel instead of closing all of excel, any ideas how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pgrep` as if it was a shell command.

https://pypi.org/project/pgrep/

Get your ID through conditionals and then kill it as Andrew said.

Regards!

EDIT:

Another approach using psutils with a loop loking for a process given a name:

```
import psutil
# Get all proces in a list
pids = psutil.pids()
print("There is", len(pids), "Process")

#Search process with this string
name_like = "evolution"

# Loop checking for the pid "name_like"
i = 0
while i<len(pids):
    print("i is", i)
    print("pid (pids[i]) is", pids[i])
    print("Proces name is", psutil.Process(pid=pids[i]).name())
    if name_like in psutil.Process(pid=pids[i]).name():
        print("KILL THIS F@*!& PROCESS")
    i+=1
```

This is the output:

```
i is 181
pid (pids[i]) is 1834
Proces name is evolution-calendar-factory
KILL THIS F@*!& PROCESS
```

Regards.